# execute javascript when a usercontrol become visible

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a usercontrol wich is visible=false when the page is loaded.
Then, it becomes visible=true.
I want some javascript to be executed when this usercontrol is set to visible=true in the code-behind.
the only solution i found is to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in the

usercontrol's code behind.
But i don't like writing my javascript in the codeBehind.

This jQuery in the usercontrol doesn't work :
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert('test');
});

The usercontrol is into an updatepanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this jQuery plugin](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/478985.aspx).  It makes use of the `onpropertychange` event in IE and the `DOMAttrModified` mutation event in supported browsers.  With it, you should be able to watch for the `visibility` property being changed.